# Mips 2d array rowsum and column product

Tags: loops, mips

```c
.data

.align 2
array:   .space  150
row:     .asciiz "Enter the amount of rows in your array(2-6): "
column:  .asciiz "Enter the amout of colums in your array(2-6): "
data:    .asciiz "Enter an array element (in row order): "
rowsum:  .asciiz "The row sums are: "
product: .asciiz "The column prdoucts are: "

# ask for rows and columns
# figure out size of the array rows X columns
# save that as the array size

.text
 main:

        la $t7,array

        # Print row string
        li $v0, 4    # system call code for print_str
        la $a0, row  # address of string to print
        syscall

        # ask for row integer value
        li $v0, 5    # syscall read_int
        syscall
        move $s0, $v0

        # print column string
        li $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
        la $a0, column # address of string to print
        syscall

        # ask for column integer value
        li   $v0, 5 # syscall read_int
        syscall
        move $s1, $v0

        # matrix
        mult $s0, $s1   # multiply row by column
        mflo $t0        # move the value from our lower register
        move $t1, $zero # set terminal to zero

        read_loop:

            # print data string
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, data
            syscall

            # ask for element array value
            li $v0, 6
            syscall

            # move the value to the array
            swc1 $f0, 0($t7)

            # increment position
            addi $t1, $t1, 1
            addi $t7, $t7, 4

            # count of matrix
            bne     $t1, $t0, read_loop # read input based on how big the matrix is. stop when we hit the end.
```

I'm not sure on how I should properly loop through the array to get the values from each row to print out as a row sum.

I have the matrix size from above in `# matrix`

But given the matrix size, how can I read 1-6 inputs. I know each input is 4 bytes. So rows could vary from 4, 8, 12, 16, 24, 28 bytes.

Would this require a branch before or after I start looping, or multiple branches?

```c
row_loop:

    # add every row value.
    # Need to read 1-6 values
    # Can I use the row value stored in $s0?

    # print sum result
    li $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
    la $a0, rowsum # address of string to print
    syscall

col_loop:

    # print column product result
    li $v0, 4       # system call code for print_str
    la $a0, product # address of string to print
    syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues with this problem is the *debugging*.

For example, you create a program version. Now run it. It *prompts* for all the data. Entering this from the console takes a *long* time. If there's a bug, you have to change something, rebuild and rerun. And ... *Reenter* the data all over again.

During testing, it's much easier to put test matrixes into `.float` statements, so *no* data entry.

What I'd do at the outset of the program, is prompt the user for a test number:

```
Enter test number (-1=stop, -2=all, 0=prompt, >0 is predefined test):
```

Another issue is how do you verify the results? In other words, how do you generate the correct results so that the program output can be verified either manually or automatically?

Thus, I'd recommend a C program that generates the test matrixes and computes the row sums and column products.

The C code that computes sums and products can serve a dual purpose as pseudo-code for the asm you wish to generate.

By doing this, we're separating [the design of] the *algorithm* from the *implementation* of that algoritm in asm.

After that, it becomes a much simpler matter to mechanically translate the C code.

---

Here's a test generator program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int opt_gen;                            // generate asm statements
int opt_T;                              // number of tests

#define ROWMIN              2
#define ROWMAX              6

int rowmax;
int colmax;
int stride;
float mtx[ROWMAX * ROWMAX];
float rowsum[ROWMAX];
float colprod[ROWMAX];

int tstno;

// getdim -- get matrix dimension
int
getdim(void)
{
    int dim;

    while (1) {
        dim = lrand48() % (ROWMIN + ROWMAX);
        dim += ROWMIN;
        if (dim <= ROWMAX)
            break;
    }

    return dim;
}

// arrshow -- output an array
void
arrshow(float *arr,int arrmax,const char *sym,const char *title)
{
    char *sep;
    int arridx;

    printf("\t# %s\n",title);
    printf("tst%2.2d_%s:\n",tstno,sym);

    printf("\t.float\t");
    sep = "";

    for (arridx = 0;  arridx < arrmax;  ++arridx) {
        printf("%s%g",sep,arr[arridx]);
        sep = ",";
    }

    printf("\n");
}

// dotst -- generate test
void
dotst(void)
{
    int rowidx;
    int colidx;
    float val;
    char *sep;

    rowmax = getdim();
    colmax = getdim();

#if 0
    stride = ROWMAX;
#else
    stride = colmax;
#endif

    if (tstno > 1)
        printf("\n");
    printf("tst%2.2d:\n",tstno);
    printf("\t.word\t%d\t# test number\n",tstno);
    if (tstno < opt_T)
        printf("\t.word\ttst%2.2d\t# pointer to next test\n",tstno + 1);
    else
        printf("\t.word\t0\t# pointer to next test\n");
    printf("\t.word\t%d\t# rowmax\n",rowmax);
    printf("\t.word\t%d\t# colmax\n",colmax);

    // generate the matrix
    printf("tst%2.2d_mtx:\n",tstno);
    for (rowidx = 0;  rowidx < rowmax;  ++rowidx) {
        printf("\t.float\t");
        sep = "";
        for (colidx = 0;  colidx < colmax;  ++colidx) {
            val = drand48();
            mtx[(rowidx * stride) + colidx] = val;
            printf("%s%g",sep,val);
            sep = ",";
        }
        printf("\t# row %d\n",rowidx);
    }

    // generate row sums
    for (rowidx = 0;  rowidx < rowmax;  ++rowidx) {
        val = 0.0;
        for (colidx = 0;  colidx < colmax;  ++colidx)
            val += mtx[(rowidx * stride) + colidx];
        rowsum[rowidx] = val;
    }

    // generate column products
    for (colidx = 0;  colidx < colmax;  ++colidx) {
        val = 1.0;
        for (rowidx = 0;  rowidx < rowmax;  ++rowidx)
            val *= mtx[(rowidx * stride) + colidx];
        colprod[colidx] = val;
    }

    // print row sums
    arrshow(rowsum,rowmax,"rowsum","row sums [indexed by row]");

    // print column products
    arrshow(colprod,colmax,"colprod","column products [indexed by column]");
}

// dogen -- generate tests for asm
void
dogen(void)
{

    for (tstno = 1;  tstno <= opt_T;  ++tstno)
        dotst();
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'g':
            opt_gen = 1;
            break;
        case 'T':
            opt_T = atoi(cp + 2);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (opt_T <= 0)
        opt_T = 20;

    srand48(0xDEADBEEF);

#if 0
    if (opt_gen)
        dogen();
    else
        doloop();
#else
    dogen();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the output of the test generator program:

```
tst01:
    .word   1   # test number
    .word   tst02   # pointer to next test
    .word   6   # rowmax
    .word   2   # colmax
tst01_mtx:
    .float  0.0480832,0.925215  # row 0
    .float  0.511196,0.342399   # row 1
    .float  0.0231708,0.77913   # row 2
    .float  0.458211,0.657552   # row 3
    .float  0.192286,0.13829    # row 4
    .float  0.718801,0.00220358 # row 5
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst01_rowsum:
    .float  0.973298,0.853595,0.8023,1.11576,0.330576,0.721005
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst01_colprod:
    .float  3.60698e-05,4.94575e-05

tst02:
    .word   2   # test number
    .word   tst03   # pointer to next test
    .word   6   # rowmax
    .word   6   # colmax
tst02_mtx:
    .float  0.849782,0.546568,0.937853,0.864108,0.305004,0.00756697 # row 0
    .float  0.739542,0.708572,0.207939,0.5616,0.11377,0.567681  # row 1
    .float  0.0564002,0.221843,0.808113,0.0481284,0.733861,0.291474 # row 2
    .float  0.49113,0.243682,0.547646,0.954115,0.0828184,0.377302   # row 3
    .float  0.750289,0.984919,0.190717,0.0230619,0.832171,0.466742  # row 4
    .float  0.0156874,0.505762,0.220668,0.411513,0.0195486,0.726932 # row 5
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst02_rowsum:
    .float  3.51088,2.8991,2.15982,2.69669,3.2479,1.90011
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst02_colprod:
    .float  0.000204894,0.010429,0.00363223,0.000211483,3.43085e-05,0.000160282

tst03:
    .word   3   # test number
    .word   tst04   # pointer to next test
    .word   2   # rowmax
    .word   5   # colmax
tst03_mtx:
    .float  0.970571,0.231291,0.436997,0.822847,0.771793    # row 0
    .float  0.820889,0.118123,0.628661,0.148443,0.447973    # row 1
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst03_rowsum:
    .float  3.2335,2.16409
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst03_colprod:
    .float  0.796731,0.0273208,0.274723,0.122146,0.345742

tst04:
    .word   4   # test number
    .word   tst05   # pointer to next test
    .word   3   # rowmax
    .word   6   # colmax
tst04_mtx:
    .float  0.618794,0.303102,0.28536,0.883616,0.0425207,0.370875   # row 0
    .float  0.233947,0.784831,0.109683,0.21696,0.117412,0.224096    # row 1
    .float  0.629818,0.325219,0.204525,0.294107,0.760322,0.728664   # row 2
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst04_rowsum:
    .float  2.50427,1.68693,2.94265
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst04_colprod:
    .float  0.0911756,0.0773644,0.00640146,0.056383,0.00379587,0.0605604

tst05:
    .word   5   # test number
    .word   tst06   # pointer to next test
    .word   3   # rowmax
    .word   4   # colmax
tst05_mtx:
    .float  0.358229,0.576659,0.339637,0.137463 # row 0
    .float  0.521153,0.798593,0.834109,0.137639 # row 1
    .float  0.0203656,0.614799,0.10029,0.903942 # row 2
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst05_rowsum:
    .float  1.41199,2.29149,1.6394
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst05_colprod:
    .float  0.0038021,0.283125,0.0284116,0.0171028

tst06:
    .word   6   # test number
    .word   tst07   # pointer to next test
    .word   2   # rowmax
    .word   2   # colmax
tst06_mtx:
    .float  0.0710807,0.79236   # row 0
    .float  0.166013,0.243027   # row 1
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst06_rowsum:
    .float  0.86344,0.40904
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst06_colprod:
    .float  0.0118003,0.192564

tst07:
    .word   7   # test number
    .word   tst08   # pointer to next test
    .word   2   # rowmax
    .word   6   # colmax
tst07_mtx:
    .float  0.525881,0.767693,0.615366,0.684871,0.658207,0.0927842  # row 0
    .float  0.711593,0.570353,0.650287,0.810089,0.557573,0.23852    # row 1
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst07_rowsum:
    .float  3.3448,3.53841
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst07_colprod:
    .float  0.374213,0.437856,0.400164,0.554807,0.366998,0.0221309

tst08:
    .word   8   # test number
    .word   tst09   # pointer to next test
    .word   2   # rowmax
    .word   2   # colmax
tst08_mtx:
    .float  0.21128,0.484587    # row 0
    .float  0.292336,0.980593   # row 1
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst08_rowsum:
    .float  0.695866,1.27293
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst08_colprod:
    .float  0.0617646,0.475182

tst09:
    .word   9   # test number
    .word   tst10   # pointer to next test
    .word   6   # rowmax
    .word   4   # colmax
tst09_mtx:
    .float  0.424862,0.0964705,0.915842,0.77812 # row 0
    .float  0.291517,0.279445,0.129929,0.757929 # row 1
    .float  0.475404,0.655913,0.0729621,0.00775924  # row 2
    .float  0.263494,0.222636,0.183699,0.381668 # row 3
    .float  0.290414,0.101607,0.0826193,0.1799  # row 4
    .float  0.337035,0.911792,0.0123981,0.769976    # row 5
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst09_rowsum:
    .float  2.21529,1.45882,1.21204,1.0515,0.654541,2.0312
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst09_colprod:
    .float  0.00151858,0.000364714,1.63368e-06,0.00024193

tst10:
    .word   10  # test number
    .word   tst11   # pointer to next test
    .word   3   # rowmax
    .word   2   # colmax
tst10_mtx:
    .float  0.927257,0.0815354  # row 0
    .float  0.921494,0.600199   # row 1
    .float  0.594305,0.504229   # row 2
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst10_rowsum:
    .float  1.00879,1.52169,1.09853
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst10_colprod:
    .float  0.507811,0.0246757

tst11:
    .word   11  # test number
    .word   tst12   # pointer to next test
    .word   2   # rowmax
    .word   2   # colmax
tst11_mtx:
    .float  0.216704,0.835793   # row 0
    .float  0.589206,0.622495   # row 1
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst11_rowsum:
    .float  1.0525,1.2117
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst11_colprod:
    .float  0.127683,0.520277

tst12:
    .word   12  # test number
    .word   tst13   # pointer to next test
    .word   2   # rowmax
    .word   6   # colmax
tst12_mtx:
    .float  0.799863,0.268639,0.370484,0.509241,0.345844,0.0568862  # row 0
    .float  0.0554226,0.346426,0.63628,0.933348,0.322327,0.726197   # row 1
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst12_rowsum:
    .float  2.35096,3.02
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst12_colprod:
    .float  0.0443305,0.0930634,0.235732,0.475299,0.111475,0.0413106

tst13:
    .word   13  # test number
    .word   tst14   # pointer to next test
    .word   6   # rowmax
    .word   4   # colmax
tst13_mtx:
    .float  0.817304,0.609118,0.754376,0.712011 # row 0
    .float  0.557027,0.676689,0.358653,0.237841 # row 1
    .float  0.167921,0.0921725,0.80346,0.215156 # row 2
    .float  0.741307,0.405931,0.0239142,0.236406    # row 3
    .float  0.913345,0.867056,0.177716,0.71794  # row 4
    .float  0.172439,0.627781,0.0726845,0.879335    # row 5
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst13_rowsum:
    .float  2.89281,1.83021,1.27871,1.40756,2.67606,1.75224
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst13_colprod:
    .float  0.00892551,0.00839458,6.71508e-05,0.00543784

tst14:
    .word   14  # test number
    .word   tst15   # pointer to next test
    .word   4   # rowmax
    .word   5   # colmax
tst14_mtx:
    .float  0.0444047,0.985519,0.291545,0.747228,0.443979   # row 0
    .float  0.711087,0.534498,0.508636,0.748564,0.629221    # row 1
    .float  0.0881322,0.779609,0.928828,0.415243,0.578218   # row 2
    .float  0.259088,0.992353,0.260463,0.376166,0.624528    # row 3
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst14_rowsum:
    .float  2.51268,3.13201,2.79003,2.5126
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst14_colprod:
    .float  0.000720995,0.407525,0.0358751,0.0873703,0.100881

tst15:
    .word   15  # test number
    .word   tst16   # pointer to next test
    .word   2   # rowmax
    .word   5   # colmax
tst15_mtx:
    .float  0.530169,0.086245,0.070489,0.164902,0.109771    # row 0
    .float  0.509496,0.366888,0.128401,0.252501,0.0109814   # row 1
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst15_rowsum:
    .float  0.961577,1.26827
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst15_colprod:
    .float  0.270119,0.0316423,0.00905088,0.0416379,0.00120544

tst16:
    .word   16  # test number
    .word   tst17   # pointer to next test
    .word   6   # rowmax
    .word   4   # colmax
tst16_mtx:
    .float  0.49342,0.289792,0.366951,0.921996  # row 0
    .float  0.721338,0.213262,0.911397,0.248489 # row 1
    .float  0.855794,0.155251,0.765392,0.926219 # row 2
    .float  0.608776,0.790685,0.603981,0.902971 # row 3
    .float  0.282509,0.951709,0.509161,0.48244  # row 4
    .float  0.772914,0.416316,0.309304,0.291831 # row 5
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst16_rowsum:
    .float  2.07216,2.09449,2.70266,2.90641,2.22582,1.79036
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst16_colprod:
    .float  0.0404899,0.00300582,0.024348,0.0269772

tst17:
    .word   17  # test number
    .word   tst18   # pointer to next test
    .word   2   # rowmax
    .word   6   # colmax
tst17_mtx:
    .float  0.46297,0.216732,0.732362,0.40035,0.3825,0.976923   # row 0
    .float  0.126104,0.340014,0.6256,0.958355,0.327664,0.891615 # row 1
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst17_rowsum:
    .float  3.17184,3.26935
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst17_colprod:
    .float  0.0583822,0.0736917,0.458166,0.383678,0.125332,0.871039

tst18:
    .word   18  # test number
    .word   tst19   # pointer to next test
    .word   3   # rowmax
    .word   2   # colmax
tst18_mtx:
    .float  0.749495,0.954779   # row 0
    .float  0.0476438,0.743898  # row 1
    .float  0.679273,0.342579   # row 2
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst18_rowsum:
    .float  1.70427,0.791542,1.02185
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst18_colprod:
    .float  0.024256,0.243319

tst19:
    .word   19  # test number
    .word   tst20   # pointer to next test
    .word   6   # rowmax
    .word   3   # colmax
tst19_mtx:
    .float  0.562899,0.984625,0.495615  # row 0
    .float  0.603749,0.240201,0.905512  # row 1
    .float  0.918128,0.649461,0.366722  # row 2
    .float  0.295691,0.0880594,0.0199822    # row 3
    .float  0.211216,0.127633,0.265338  # row 4
    .float  0.132539,0.585006,0.534659  # row 5
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst19_rowsum:
    .float  2.04314,1.74946,1.93431,0.403733,0.604187,1.2522
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst19_colprod:
    .float  0.00258285,0.00100995,0.000466548

tst20:
    .word   20  # test number
    .word   0   # pointer to next test
    .word   6   # rowmax
    .word   3   # colmax
tst20_mtx:
    .float  0.351139,0.880843,0.407246  # row 0
    .float  0.0540183,0.30472,0.0619591 # row 1
    .float  0.137091,0.783589,0.200142  # row 2
    .float  0.586626,0.480319,0.0743153 # row 3
    .float  0.243075,0.125374,0.427872  # row 4
    .float  0.459117,0.607819,0.747043  # row 5
    # row sums [indexed by row]
tst20_rowsum:
    .float  1.63923,0.420698,1.12082,1.14126,0.796321,1.81398
    # column products [indexed by column]
tst20_colprod:
    .float  0.000170237,0.00769839,0.000119961
```